# How to adjust outer table borders in a table with spacing between cells?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have the following problem: in a table with spacing *between* cells (**table 1** in image (1) below) I wish to remove the side borders completely, so that it has no side borders (like **table 2** in image (1)). In other words, I wish to do a "combination" of sorts of the characteristics of table 1 and 2. When I try to remove the side borders, however, it becomes worse, as in image (2).

I've tried to set the side borders to a white colour, but this does not remedy my problem.
Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Original tables:

[image]

Erroneous table:

[image]

EDIT:
I've tried two approaches:

1. Selected entire table → selected Borders drop-down menu → deselected side both borders. This leads to the erroneous tables as per the picture above.
2. Tried using the Borders and Shading-menu to deselect side borders. Leads to the error as per above.

Comment: Select the whole table and remove the left and right borders completely (don't make them white). Look like you have double line borders for the top and bottom as well instead of single line borders.

Comment: I am also using Word 2010 and was unable to duplicate your problem. Borders were easily adjusted and removed as expected. Can you elaborate how you are attempting to adjust and/or remove them?

Comment: I've updated my answer. In the second attempt, I tried doing this: [link to my attempt to remove side borders](http://s4.postimg.org/5fqk29t9p/tables_error_2.jpg).

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my own problem. I did as follows:

- Selected entire table
- Right clicked table and selected *Table Properties*
- Selected *Borders and Shading* from inside the Table Properties dialog
- In the Borders and Shading-dialog I clicked the Box-setting (see left-hand side of Borders and Shading)
- De-selected both side borders in the table preview (right-hand side of dialog)

The result looks like this:
[the result I got (and wanted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVTdr.png).
Thank you all for taking your time to help me!